# Saving multiple columns/variables with different sizes in the same CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, hdf5

I have about 100 columns with a large number of values in each one of them. I want to save them in a CSV file so I can read the file and use the values in these columns in my code. The only problem is that these columns are not related to each other and they have different lengths, so they are technically not part of a dataframe.

I was thinking of storing them in a CSV file, and then read each column separately and use it in my code. Because these columns are in different lengths and are not part of a dataframe, I guess that I have to filter out the `NaN` values in each column before I use it.

I wonder if there is a simpler way in which I can store (in a file) and read these columns. I am thinking of maybe lists or something similar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I have about 100 columns with a large number of values in each one of them.` How is your data stored in Python? NumPy arrays, Pandas series, Python list, something else?

Comment: Where do you get the data from? Who or what program saves the data into file?
As your columns are not related to each other and have different length I suggest using a line for each column. In that way you can parse the csv line by line and extract each "column" after the other. You could also save yout data as xml or jason, which ware extremly flexible data storage formats with great support across programming languages.

Comment: Thanks jpp and jochen. The data have been created manually and stored in a CSV file. I usually read the CSV file and put the data in a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Hi jochen. I was thinking of saving the values of each variable in a single line, but it would be easier for the person who is responsible about data entry to work with excel columns than rows. I unfortunately do not have any experience of manually saving data in jason or xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV is not a format well suited for your task.

Since you already have a sequence of dataframes, I suggest you consider HDF5 for storing your dataframes efficiently in a single file. You can, at the same time, enable compression:

```
for idx, df in enumerate(list_of_dfs):
    df.to_hdf('data.h5', f'df_{idx}', complib='zlib', complevel=5)
```

This attaches an ordered identifier to each dataframe, i.e. `df_0`, `df_1`, etc. You can then read a specific dataframe via `pd.read_hdf`. For example:

```
first_df = pd.read_hdf('data.h5', key='df_0')
```